# Unity Vuforia Xcode build error: "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64"

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm currently trying to build a project (that worked previously) in Xcode. It's a Unity project that uses the Vuforia plugin and it builds to Android flawlessly.

When building in Xcode I get the following error message:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_UnityRenderBufferMTLTexture", referenced from:
      PlatformiOS::setRenderBuffers(void*) in libVuforiaUnityPlayer.a(PlatformiOS.o)
  "_UnityCurrentMTLCommandEncoder", referenced from:
      PlatformiOS::setRenderBuffers(void*) in libVuforiaUnityPlayer.a(PlatformiOS.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have included Security.framework and SystemConfiguration.framework in the project.

Unity 5.5.0f3; Vuforia SDK v5.5.9; XCode 8.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by updating Vuforia in the Unity project, although, when before the update I didn't delete the Vuforia files in the Plugins folder. I tried doing a proper update of Vuforia previously, which failed.

So steps:
1 - Delete Assets/Vuforia

2 - Update VuforiaCamera.cs (Assets/Scripts/Vuforia)to the code below

3 - Import latest Vuforia package

4 - Profit!

```
public class VuforiaCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool mVuforiaStarted = false;

    void Start()
    {
        VuforiaARController vuforia = VuforiaARController.Instance;

        if (vuforia != null)
            vuforia.RegisterVuforiaStartedCallback(StartAfterVuforia);
    }

    private void StartAfterVuforia()
    {
        mVuforiaStarted = true;
        SetAutofocus();
    }

    void OnApplicationPause(bool pause)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            // App resumed
            if (mVuforiaStarted)
            {
                // App resumed and vuforia already started
                // but lets start it again...
                SetAutofocus(); // This is done because some android devices lose the auto focus after resume
                // this was a bug in vuforia 4 and 5. I haven't checked 6, but the code is harmless anyway
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetAutofocus()
    {
        if (CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode(CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO))
        {
            Debug.Log("Autofocus set");
        }
        else
        {
            // never actually seen a device that doesn't support this, but just in case
            Debug.Log("this device doesn't support auto focus");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Vuforia has "VuforiaCamera.cs" ? Im using 6.2.10 and has no VuforiaCamera to update

Comment: @DanielArantesLoverde I am facing the same problem. I don’t see any vuforiacamera script there. How you solve this problem. Please help

Comment: @vanshika Sorry man, i cant remember what i did. But i probably change Unity version, or remake the project from scratch... if i remember, i post here, but probably i remake it